# PHP enter percentage number round to 2 decimal places not working

Tags: php, math, rounding

php number round to 2 decimal places not working my number is `0.00000000000000000000001` and I want result as `0.01`. I tried php [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function php [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function but they didn't work for me.

Comment: Are you saying the smallest value you want returned is 0.01..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a simple function that returns either the rounded value or the minimum value you would like...

```
function round_special($x)
{
    if ($x == 0) return 0;

    $rounded = round($x, 2);
    $minValue = 0.01;

    if ($rounded < $minValue) {
        return number_format($minValue, 2);
    } else {
        return number_format($rounded, 2);
    }
}
```

So, results would look like:

```
$x = 0.00000000000000000000001;
echo round_special($x);     // 0.01

echo round_special(0.0001); // 0.01
echo round_special(55);     // 55.00
echo round_special(0.6);    // 0.06
```

Comment: this is working for all cases but in one case it causing issue if the x will be the 0 then the function will return 0.01 so its the problem

Answer (score 1):

0.01 is far far greater than 0.00000000000000000000001. You can not round it to 0.01 . 0.006 can be rounded to 0.01 because they are very close to each other.

Comment: so there's no solution?

Comment: This is not about whether there is solution or not. What you are trying to achieve is wrong. It will give you wrong result.

Comment: I know that my expected result was wrong but as per enter percentage I have to that for further process

Comment: You can process further with 0.00000000000000000000001 and then try to round up the end result.

Answer (score 0):

Number_format() and round() will not work in your case.

This functions adjust the decimals as per original math rules

in your case result will be always 0.00...as .01 will get converts to 0.0

Comment: so there's no solution?