# Round function problem, show only 3 decimals of a number OpenCart / PHP

Tags: php, variables, numbers, opencart

I need to extract from normal OpenCart price the TVA and add another TVA with I have succeeded but the problem I get many decimals and I need only 3. I get 14.423123123 and I only need 14.423

My code {{ price/ 1.19 * 1.05 }}

Anybody knows the solutions?

Thank you!

{{ round(price/ 1.19 * 1.05, 3) }}

Comment: Well I get Uncaught Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "sprintf" function 
For {{ sprintf('%.3f', price / 1.19 * 1.05) }} 
Maybe I don't write it correctly?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it works. Thank you for solution!!

Comment: Just suggestion.... The best way all calculation to do in a corresponding controller file and then retrieve all in your twig template file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP enter percentage number round to 2 decimal places not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733886/php-enter-percentage-number-round-to-2-decimal-places-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The template engine you are using is [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/format.html). So you can use following syntax. This will take any number and represent it as a float with three digits after decimal point. It will round automatically.

```
{{ '%.3f' | format(price / 1.19 * 1.05) }}
```